# Does modern automobile windshield (windscreen) glass have manufacturer surface coatings owners/maintainers should be aware of?

Tags: cleaning, windshield

For example, once officially sanctioned in manufacturer windshield service documents, feldspar-powder containing Bon Ami 1886 Formula Cleaning Powder now cautions for *"vintage auto windshields (not modern windshields, which often have coatings)"* - these sorts of glass warnings, also noted with lesser Mohs-scale abrasives, surprised me as I only imagined something rare like a projected heads-up display might call for any coating, and that presumably only on the interior.

(The question originally arose from an investigation into cleaning methods for interior windshield fog/films resistant to everyday spray-and-wipe cleaning. Likely a build-up of plasticizers outgassed from interior plastics, the very-minimal published science implicates urethanes as the principal source. Online car-care advice for this problem varied except in that virtually all include an initial abrasive step, presumably to physically break-up the film before removal with a traditional cleaner and microfiber cloth.)

Answer (score 2):

Exterior, [hydrophobic (Ceramic) coatings](http://www.carwindshields.info/how-a-windshield-is-made), similar to rain-x but lasts up to 7 or more years. Is applied during the manufacture of the glass.

Interior is [Metal Oxide](https://info.glass.com/metallized-windshield-purpose/), same as metallized tint but is a coating applied during manufacture of glass.